# Android: No compatible targets were found yet AVD available

Tags: android, eclipse, android-virtual-device

When I Run As > Android Application I get the "No compatible targets were found" dialog box. The Log says:

```
Failed to find an AVD compatible with target 'Google APIs'.
```

The Manifest states:

```
    <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

however it appears I have a compatible AVD. For example, I have AVDs with API Level 8, 10 and 16. Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Given this, why am I getting the "No compatible targets were found" dialog box and how do I avoid it?

====
UPDATE

When I click No to the "No compatible targets were found" dialog box I get the Android Device Chooser dialog. I can then select an Android device (in the Launch New Android Device section), click OK and the app launches. So, clearly I do have a "compatible target".

UPDATE 2

I have the Google APIs installed. E.g. see this screenshot:
[image: Google APIs]

UPDATE 3

I also have the Google APIs installed for API Level 17. E.g. see:
[image: Google APIs]

Answer (score 1):

//you need to install Google API

you have only installed Android API your SDK didn't have `Google APi >10`

your `android:targetSdkVersion="17"`

so install

```
Google APIs 4.2.2
```

Answer (score 0):

Install google API's also , you have  installed only sdk's..
[image]

Answer (score 0):

From sdk manager install google api for api level 17.

Answer (score 0):

**guys i fixed it ....**

> i had the same problem, and i fixed it by installing the **samsung
>   kies** for here: [Download Samsung Kies](http://www.samsung.com/us/kies/.).